# How to unit test writing a file to AWS Lambda output stream?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda implemented in java. The lambda generates a file, then writes it to the output, using the Base64 encoder. I'm trying to write a unit test for it, but it enters an infinite loop when the file is written.

What I'd like to do is capture what is written to the encodedStream in the unit test, write it to the temporary folder, and then compare the contents to the expected contents, but the test hangs until eventually an out of memory exception is thrown.

Lambda code

```
public class MyLambda implements RequestStreamHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MyLambda.class);

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(@Nonnull InputStream inputStream, @Nonnull OutputStream outputStream, @Nonnull Context context) {

        try (OutputStream encodedStream = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(outputStream);){

            encodedStream.write("This is written to file".getBytes());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            LOGGER.info("IOException occurred ", e);

        }

     }

}
```

Unit test

```
public class MyLambdaTest {

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void testRequest() throws IOException {

        MyLambda myLambda = new MyLambda();
        InputStream inputStream = mock(InputStream.class);
        OutputStream mockOutputStream = mock(OutputStream.class);
        Context mockContext = mock(Context.class);

        doNothing().when(mockOutputStream).write(anyInt());
        doNothing().when(mockOutputStream).write(any(byte[].class));
        doNothing().when(mockOutputStream).write(any(byte[].class), anyInt(), anyInt());

        myLambda.handleRequest(inputStream, mockOutputStream, mockContext);

        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(temporaryFolder.newFile(), <captured bytes>);

    }

}
```

I have deployed the code to AWS, so I know it works, but I'd like to have a proper unit test written for it for future builds

Comment: Note - both solutions below worked, but the one I marked as the accepted answer was closer to what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mocking the `OutputStream`, you can create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. It's basically just an array of bytes that implements `OutputStream`. And then you can verify the correct content was written with `ByteArrayOutputSteam#toBytes()`, or `ByteArrayOutputStream#toString()`

Answer (score 0):

```
FileOutputStream fout =
        new FileOutputStream(temporaryFolder.newFile("testout.txt"));

MyLambda myLambda = new MyLambda();

myLambda.handleRequest(null, fout, null);

fout.close();
```

Hi Joseph,

Please find my attempt above. I have used a real `FileOutputStream`.